Github Action Workflow not running on branches
I have a Github action workflow that looks like this:
name: Android Build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches-ignore:
      - master-preview
      - develop-preview
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/android_build.yml'
      - 'Android/**'
      - 'Web/public/assetlinks.json'
      - 'Web/public/android.webmanifest'
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - 'android/preview-v*'
      - 'android/v*'
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/android.yml'
      - 'Android/**'
      - 'Web/public/assetlinks.json'
      - 'Web/public/android.webmanifest'
    tags:
      - 'android/testing-v*'
      - 'android/v*'

jobs:
  lint-checks:
    name: "Lint Checks"
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
...

So I created a branch, for instance, android/preview-v123456 and pushed it to Github, and I'd expect this job would run, but it didn't. Am I using the wrong query syntax here? Or it'd only run when there's a PR being merged to this branch?

Did you commit and push your changes to the remote branch? Are the changes under one of the specified paths?

Yes. I actually discover something. The job won't run when I create the branch, it'll only run if I made some changes to the branch and triggered an update.
